# htaccess rule confulictle when i add new rule in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to redirecy this 
from

```
www.example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=12
```

to

```
www.example.com/article/category/12`
```

i write the rule for this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/general_help/category\.php\?id=([0-9]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/category/%1? [L,R]
```

This redirect me  FROM

```
www.example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=12
```

to

```
www.example.com/article/category/12
```

But i  also redirect

from

```
www.example.com/babycare/general_help
```

to

```
www.example.com/article
```

SO what should i do??i try to add different rule but that rule confulict the above rule and both stop working

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^babycare/general_help$ article [R=301,NC,L]
```

Use this code before your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/general_help/category\.php\?id=([0-9]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/category/%1? [L,R]
```

Maybe this could help you